# System.DateTime.Now returns only Month and Date sometimes

Tags: c#

I have used `System.DateTime.Now` property to get current date and time with hours. but sometimes it returns only date and month. Is it possible that `System.DateTime.Now` returns only Month and Date?

Comment: No, it's not possible

Comment: It's not a function, it's a property

Comment: sometimes it happens that in string i only get date and month and rest of the things is null.

Comment: @MoinuddinPatel `DateTime.Now` returns (unsurprisingly) a `DateTime`, if you're converting it to `String` somehow, you need to share your code for anyone to help you.

Comment: Show the code that does that, then...

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: You should show the code where you have observed the missing `DateTime` portions. You probably have converted the `DateTime` to string(f.e. indirectly with your GUI).

Comment: @MoinuddinPatel: Then sometimes it happens that you've made a mistake or written incorrect code.  Stop assuming that the .NET Framework itself must be broken and that your code must be flawless and try actually debugging your code.

Comment: When i m creating a file with system.DateTime.now() then it stores only 0921 rest of the things is not stored.

Comment: May be code goes wrong sometimes.

Comment: @MoinuddinPatel: `"May be code goes wrong sometimes."` - Admitting that your code could possibly be mistaken is a good first step.  *Debugging* your code is the next step.  (Or at least *actually looking at it*.)

Comment: @MoinuddinPatel you could start by editing your question and adding a [mcve].

Comment: @David Started debugging code but sometime only happens not always

Comment: @MoinuddinPatel: Well that's unfortunate.  But if you ever have an actual question that Stack Overflow could help with, do let us know.  "I wrote some code that I'm not showing you and something isn't working" isn't a question we can answer.

Answer (score 1):

`System.DateTime` hasn't function `Now()` it has property `Now`. 
From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Now property returns a DateTime value that represents the current
>   date and time on the local computer. Note that there is a difference
>   between a DateTime value, which represents the number of ticks that
>   have elapsed since midnight of January 1, 0001, and the string
>   representation of that DateTime value, which expresses a date and time
>   value in a culture-specific-specific format.

So, `Now` always has time part. Propably you have some bug with convert it to sting.

Here same example from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
      String[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "en-GB", "fr-FR",
                                "de-DE", "ru-RU" };

      foreach (var cultureName in cultureNames) {
         var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
         Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", cultureName,
                           localDate.ToString(culture));
      }
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
//       en-US: 6/19/2015 10:03:06 AM
//       en-GB: 19/06/2015 10:03:06
//       fr-FR: 19/06/2015 10:03:06
//       de-DE: 19.06.2015 10:03:06
//       ru-RU: 19.06.2015 10:03:06
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your string format is not correct. Please be careful with the format of the strings as the format is case sensitive. This page explains more about formatting a datetime to a string https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

You can create custom formats using the formats on that page, there are also many examples here:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/